# How to assign a value that was passed through Navigator.pushNamed as the initial value to a variable in the second screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I am passing an object called `Object1` from `Screen 1` to `Screen 2` through `Navigator.pushNamed`.
I want to assign a value of the `Object1` to a variable as the initial value in the second screen. **But that value should be able to change later on user interactions in the `Screen 2`.**

After assigning the arguments to a variable first like this,

```
String age;
Object Object1;
Map arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map;
```

I tried assigning the passed arguments in the initState.

```
@override
void initState() {
  Object1 = arguments['Object1];
  age = Object1.age;
super.initState();
}
```

But flutter throws null when I try to assign argument values to a variable in the initState method.
Then I assigned the arguments to the variables inside the build method and it worked.

But in my case, the value of the `age` variable needs to change on button clicks on the `Screen 2`, therefore `Object1.age` should be only assigned to the `age` variable as the initial value.
Since build method also runs when I make a button click, `age` variable is being assigned with the same value that came from the arguments again, therefore it doesn't change.

How to fix this issue? I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the constructor of the second screen to receive arguments

```
 class Screen2 {
     Map arguments
    
      Article(
          {this.arguments});
    }
```

Comment: Can I receive arguments using a constructor even if I'm sending the arguments in a `Navigator.pushNamed` on the first screen?

Comment: yes at the routes -


final args = settings.arguments
 return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          return Screen2(
           arguments: args,
            
          );
        },
      );

Comment: But on the `Screen 1`, I will still have to push the arguments in `MaterialPageRoute`. I want to send the arguments inside a `Navigator.pushNamed`. Not inside a `MaterialPageRoute`.

Answer (score 0):

Add
"required this.variable_name"     in the second screen
Now add the value in the "navigator.push" function
For example :
"(age:16)"

Comment: Yes, but I want to send the arguments inside a `Navigator.pushNamed`. Not inside a `Navigator.push`.